# Changes to the React project are not visible until I restart or rebuild the docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker

My project consists of four parts, two of which are Nginx and React. All containers run and work normally, except for one problem: the container with React does not react to any changes. Not only does it not update the page automatically, but even if the page is reloaded via Ctrl F5, the changes are not visible. Changes are visible only if I restart or rebuild a container. What can be the problem and how can I fix it?

Parts of docker-compose.yaml and docker-compose.local.yaml:

```
  frontend:
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./api:${API_DIRECTORY}
    networks:
      dockertemplate:
        ipv4_address: ${FRONTEND_IPV4}

  nginx:
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-nginx
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
    volumes:
      - ./api:${API_DIRECTORY}
      - ./frontend:${FRONTEND_DIRECTORY}
    depends_on:
      - api
    environment:
      API_DIRECTORY: ${API_DIRECTORY}
      FRONTEND_DIRECTORY: ${FRONTEND_DIRECTORY}
    networks:
      dockertemplate:
        ipv4_address: ${NGINX_IPV4}
```

```
  frontend:
    build:
      dockerfile: ../docker/frontend/Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: npm start
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:${FRONTEND_DIRECTORY}
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: dev
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: true
      WDS_SOCKET_PORT: 0

  nginx:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./docker/certs/local:/etc/nginx/certs
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8443:8443
    environment:
      NGINX_HOST: ${NGINX_HOST_LOCAL}
      NGINX_PORT: ${NGINX_PORT_LOCAL}
      NGINX_CERT_CRT: ${NGINX_CERT_CRT_LOCAL}
      NGINX_CERT_KEY: ${NGINX_CERT_KEY_LOCAL}
```

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ${NGINX_HOST};

    return 301 https://${NGINX_HOST};
}

server {
    listen ${NGINX_PORT} ssl http2;
    server_name ${NGINX_HOST};

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/${NGINX_CERT_CRT};
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/${NGINX_CERT_KEY};

    root ${API_DIRECTORY}/public;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend:3000;
        root ${FRONTEND_DIRECTORY}/public;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        add_header Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate, max-age=3153600";
    }

    location ~ ^/(/|static/|images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|dist/|media/|locales/|logo192.png|robots.txt|favicon.ico|manifest.json|.+\.hot-update.js) {
       proxy_pass http://frontend:3000;
       root ${FRONTEND_DIRECTORY}/public;
       access_log off;
       add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
       expires 1s;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api:5000;
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        root ${API_DIRECTORY}/public;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        fastcgi_pass api:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        internal;
    }

    location ~* .+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|js|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|mp4|svg|svgz})$ {
        root ${API_DIRECTORY}/public;
        add_header Cache-Control "private, max-age=3153600";
    }
}

server {
    listen 13306 ssl;
    server_name ${NGINX_HOST};

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/${NGINX_CERT_CRT};
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/${NGINX_CERT_KEY};

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://mysql:13306;
    }
}
```

Frontend container Dockerfile:

```
ARG NODE_VERSION=20.11

FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}

WORKDIR /var/www/dockertemplate/frontend

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm cache clean -f
RUN npm cache verify
RUN npm install -g react-scripts
#RUN npm audit fix

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

npm install

set -e

if [ "${1#-}" != "${1}" ] || [ -z "$(command -v "${1}")" ]; then
  set -- node "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

I've tried a different settings of a containers in docker-compose files and Dockerfile, as well as recreating empty react project several times, but it didn't work. I still need to restart a container to see any changes

OS - Windows 10, if it's important

Comment: That sounds like the way I'd normally expect Docker to work.  Can you use `node` on the host without Docker, if you need a live-reloading environment?

Answer (score 2):

We can't see what's in your `docker-entrypoint.sh` file, but based on how React works, I assume it builds your code to be production-ready. If this is the case, then it would make sense why it's not updating live or updating at all unless you rebuild. You're telling the container to build it once and then run from that production-level build.

If that isn't the case, are you using that volume attached to the frontend container to pass the code in? If so and you're using Windows, it acts like a network file share, so it's not super great for trying to build on that.

In the future, you'd want to consider using a [minimum reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can better see the problem. Trying to sift through all this configuration files is tough to look over and see a small problem.

I would assume it's a problem because it's building the JS since you mention it not updating at all until after you rebuild the container. Docker's new Dev Environments are good for testing code like this that you're actively developing. They make it easy to make code modifications on the fly.

### Edit:

If that volume you're using on the frontend container is going to the code directory, that's a start. If it isn't, you should consider adding one to put your code edits into the container's file system (or at least to be accessible to the container). Once you have the code edits going to the container, see if using `npm start dev` in your docker-compose.yaml (as opposed to `npm start`). That should tell React that it's in a development environment and to look for changes to the code and reload upon a change.

If that doesn't work, you could try messing around with the commands and volumes some more.

Comment: I added docker-entrypoint.sh

Regarding the above about working on Windows, other containers (for example, PHP) work fine. But still, what can be done in my situation?